# How implement texture sampling function like texture in glsl

Tags: c++, opengl

I had implement a texture sampling function, but the result was not same to the texture in glsl. My code is like following:

```
// This function warp sample from texture
float MyTexture::Sampler(float u,float v)
{
    float _u = (u - floorf(u)) * float(this->width - 1);
    float _v = (v - floorf(v)) * float(this->height - 1);
    int x0 = floorf(_u);
    int y0 = floorf(_v);
    int x1 = (x0 + 1) % (this->width - 1);
    int y1 = (y0 + 1) % (this->height - 1);

    float u1 = (_u - floorf(_u));
    float v1 = (_v - floorf(_v));
    float u0 = 1.0f - u1;
    float v0 = 1.0f - v1;

    float a = (float)texture[x0 * 4 + y0 * this->width * 4];
    float b = (float)texture[x0 * 4 + y1 * this->width * 4];
    float c = (float)texture[x1 * 4 + y0 * this->width * 4];
    float d = (float)texture[x1 * 4 + y1 * this->width * 4];

    return (u0 * (v0 * a + v1 * b) + u1 * (v0 * c + v1 * d))/255;
}
```

Comment: what result you expect? what result your code produce?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to do manual bilinear filtering? 
First scale by size:

```
u = u * texwidth;
```

Then split into integer and fraction:

```
int ui = (int)u;   // works if u is positive
float uf = u - ui; // must be [0..1]
```

Do the same for v; Then sample four neighbors, nearest neighbour:

```
n[0] = sample(ui,vi); 
n[1] = sample(ui+1,vi);
n[2] = sample(ui,vi+1) 
n[3] = sample(ui+1,vi+1)
```

Then filter:

```
result = lerp ( lerp(n[0],n[1],uf), lerp(n[2],n[3],uf), vf );
```

Where lerp is linear interpolation:

```
lerp(float a, float b, float f) { return a+(b-a)*f; }
```

Doing wrapping and negative values is left if you need it. :)